# Refresh remote directory in Emacs Tramp Mode

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp, ido

I've been using Tramp mode on my Emacs to edit files remotely. I'm also using ido mode. When I add a new file in the same directory of a file I opened using Tramp, I couldn't get Tramp to find the new file(with C-x C-f). Is there a way to refresh Tramp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As documented [here](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/tramp-does-not-see-directory-changes-td242710.html), you can press <kbd>g</kbd> in the dired buffer to run `revert-buffer` and refresh the directory listing.

Comment: `g` is the usual 'refresh the buffer contents' binding, and works in lots of Emacs modes.

Answer (score 29):

Your question is about ido-mode used with tramp.  To refresh ido auto-complete while in the process of finding a file, you can press `C-l`, to execute:  `ido-reread-directory`.

Comment: Worked for me once, but not any more. No Idea why.
Says: `Symbol's value as variable is void: ido-cur-item`.

Any solutions?

Comment: @reza.safiyat that is because you need to call it within the context of opening a file or a directory. To try this, using `ido-find-file` go to a directory you want to refresh and hit "C-l" (within the ido buffer). It will refresh the directory you are currently looking at.

Comment: Funny: for me, I just went to directory I would like to refresh with `C-f` then I just press `C-l` and it have refreshed.